# Get current buffer (content) size in vim script

Tags: buffers

I'm using nvim v0.4.3 and am trying to apply some of [the tricks](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Faster_loading_of_large_files) + alpha (e.g. disabling substitution preview) to make editing large files faster.

I want to do that even to unnamed buffers (i.e. buffers without actual filenames), but I don't know how to get the size of the current buffer's content in vim script.

For named buffers, one can use `getfsize()` but it doesn't work for unnamed buffers.

`g<C-g>` displays the size in bytes, but I want to get the size info in vim script. It looks like `getbufinfo()` doesn't return the size info.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for the hello and the perfect answer!

Comment: Happy to help! Btw I found about it under `:help g_CTRL-G`, so one great piece of advice with (Neo)Vim is to always start with the help system, which is really thorough!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262902/vim-count-characters-in-a-buffer-from-a-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`wordcount()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#wordcount%28%29) function will return statistics for the current buffer, including the total number of bytes and total number of characters.

From `:help wordcount()`:

> The result is a dictionary of byte/chars/word statistics for the current buffer.  This is the same info as provided by `g_CTRL-G`.
>
> The return value includes:
>
> - `bytes`: Number of bytes in the buffer
> - `chars`: Number of chars in the buffer
> - etc.